# Copying or updating the row based on the occurrence of a row cell value

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to add a given row or update an existing row to a Google Sheet based on a specific value in the row data. My row data is represented as an array object, like this: `[id, number, date, type, url, count]`.

What I expect is that, if there exists a row with a matching `number`, I increment the `count` by 1 in the **same range** in the Google Sheet, else I add a new row with my row data.

Here's what I've tried so far, but it works only for count=2 and not beyond that.

```
function copyRowBasedOnNumber(sheetId, sheetName, rowData) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  var sheetname = sheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var count = 0;
  var matchingRow = sheetname.getLastRow();
  var values = sheetname.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var row in values) {
    for (var col in values[row]) {
      if (values[row][col] == rowData[1]) { // rowData[1] corresponds to the number
        matchingRow = row;
        count++;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if(count == 0) {
    var lastRowNum = sheetname.getLastRow();
    sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRowNum);
    rowData[5] = 1;
    sheetname.getRange(lastRowNum + 1, 1, 1, rowData.length).setValues([rowData]);
  } else {
    sheetname.getRange(parseInt(matchingRow) + 1, 6).setValue(count + 1);
  }
  return count + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. In case this helps someone in future, here's the code. Here, `count` is the value I want to check before I add a new entry or update an existing entry.

```
function copyRowToSheetWithoutDuplicate(sheetId, tabName, rowData) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  var sheetname = sheet.getSheetByName(tabName);
  var count = 0;
  var existingCount = 0;
  var existingEntryRow = 0;
  var allValues = sheetname.getDataRange().getValues();
  var numColumns = sheetname.getLastColumn();
  var numRows = sheetname.getLastRow();
  for(var i=0;i<numRows;i++) {
    var dateFromRowData = rowData[3].substring(0,10);
    var todayDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+05:30", "''yyyy-MM-dd");
     if(allValues[i][1]==rowData[1] && dateFromRowData!=todayDate) {
       count++;
       existingCount = allValues[i][6];
       existingEntryRow = i + 1;
       break;
   }
  }
  if(count == 0) {
    // insert a row and make an entry
    sheetname.insertRowAfter(numRows);
    rowData.push(1); // count
    sheetname.getRange(numRows + 1, 1, 1, rowData.length).setValues([rowData]);
    return 1;
  } else {
    // update the existing count by incrementing it by 1
    existingCount++;
    rowData.push(existingCount); // count
    sheetname.getRange(existingEntryRow, 1, 1, rowData.length).setValues([rowData]);
    return existingCount;
  }
}
```